# PHP memory_limit Won't Increase on CLI

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-limit

Evening, I am try to run a script that need a lot of memory from the command line.

System is Linux LinuxMint 3.2.0-23-generic w/ PHP Version => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6

I have `memory_limit -1` in php.ini for CLI and am also setting `ini_set( 'memory_limit', '-1' );`

but if I run `phpinfo()` via the command line it says:

```
memory_limit => 300M => -1
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

I've also tried setting the memory limit via the command on the CLI. No difference.

Thanks for the info, Sammitch, but when I am running scripts I get:

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 314572800 bytes exhausted (300MB)

It appears this is a system, issue, but I cannot fix it.

**EDIT**: after searching, I found I had set a memory limit of 300MB in my global config.php file. Be diligent!

Answer (score 4):

You're not understanding the format.

```
variable_name => default_value => current_value
```